# What does @_ mean at the beginning of code in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
A::(tmp:7):     our $_ = 1;
  DB<9> V :: _
@_ = (
   0  0
   1  '_'
   2  *main::_
   3  0
   4  '-1'
)
  DB<10>
```

The above is the output of `V :: _` at the 1st line of code,what does `@_` mean?

Answer (score 5):

[`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@_) is the variable that holds a subroutine's parameters.
When you look at it with V in the debugger, it seems to show the parameters for some internal-to-the-debugger subroutine.

Comment: What does those parameters mean?seems useless to me

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of perldoc let you look up variables with the `-v` switch, which extracts just the part you need from [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
  $ perldoc -v '@_'
   @ARG
   @_      Within a subroutine the array @_ contains the parameters passed
           to that subroutine.  See perlsub.
```

Answer (score 0):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables

> Within a subroutine the array @_ contains the parameters passed to that subroutine. Inside a subroutine, @_ is the default array for the array operators push, pop, shift, and unshift

---

In essence, `@_` is the array equivalent of `$_`

---

```
use Data::Dumper;

foo(0,'_',*main::_,0,-1);

sub foo {
   print Dumper(\@_);
}
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          '_',
          *::_,
          0,
          -1
        ];
```

Comment: That's not code, it's debugger output. It's just *showing* the contents of `@_`.

Comment: "Your code is overwriting the contents of the default `@_` array." "You are performing a list assignment". No and no.

Comment: I think you're right, I was thinking it was a `qq(...)`, a change is a-coming.  Are you sure though? I've never seen an output like that, and it looks like it's an assignment in the code.  Nevermind, it does resemble `Data::Dumper` output, with a twist.